# error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 408

Tags: django, git

I tried to install CDR in my Asterisk

But my django is with problem. The log is

```
Cloning http://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine.git to /tmp/pip-DpnGzP-build
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 408
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Complete output from command git clone -q http://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine.git /tmp/pip-DpnGzP-build:

 ----------------------------------------
Command "git clone -q http://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine.git /tmp/pip-DpnGzP-build" failed with error code 128 in None
```

How can I fix this problem with my git?

Answer from  @HBHB

```
 root@asteriskteste:/# git clone http://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache- machine.git /tmp/pip-DpnGzP-build
 Cloning into '/tmp/pip-DpnGzP-build'...
 remote: Counting objects: 1082, done.
 remote: Total 1082 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1082
 Receiving objects: 100% (1082/1082), 225.33 KiB | 369 KiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (597/597), done.
```

Comment: try cloning again without the `-q` flag and post the output

Comment: yeah, I think that this fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure either of these are your problem, but that repo moved to `django-cache-machine/django-cache-machine`, and also Github is only usable with https these days (but it should redirect http to https for you).

Comment: Right, but this installations is provide from a script. So is necessary to change in this script https://github.com/cdr-stats/cdr-stats/blob/develop/install/install-cdr-stats.sh ?:

Comment: @HBHB Thanks very much. Your solution fixed my problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: @VitorMazuco no problem :)

Comment: please, put your answer below for I accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to run `git clone` without the `-q` option as this will suppress progress of the clone. This is important when you run into an error so you can see where it manifests itself.